# How to get one record when there are multiple records using join

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Need a help for the sql query to fetch record from the below table structure:

```
Table A:
trans_id  msgid recivtime 
1          p      dd-mm-yyyy hh24i mi:ss
1          Q      dd-mm-yyyy hh24i mi:ss


Table B:
msgid      status  sendtime 
P           C       dd-mm-yyyy hh24i mi:ss
P           -        -
Q           C       dd-mm-yyyy hh24i mi:ss
```

I want to fetch for one trans_id from table A, status details from table B (only the first record from the above example), so out put should be

```
transid   msgid status sendtime
1         P      C      dd-mm-yyyy
1         Q      C      dd-mm-yyyy
```

I tried with

```
SELECT a.msgid, 
       a.recivtime, 
       b.status 
FROM   a a, 
       b b 
WHERE  a.msgid = b.msgid 
       AND a.transid = ?
```

its giving the duplicate record that present in the table B as well, to remove that I tried with `distinct` but seems didn't go through.

Thanks for help .

Comment: do you have some kind of primary key (just an column with some growing value) in both table?

Comment: Yes a primary key is there, but requirement is to fetch the transaction details, so querying by trans id, please note in table A, trans id can be multiple time and each trans id in Table A will have unique message is that is P,Q,R, etc and in Table B, message id can be multiple but intention is to get single record for one messagid from table B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then `{transid, msgid}` is key in Table A, meaning that for every `transid` there will be one or more `msgid`. For every `msgid` there will be one or more detail records in Table B. You said there was not a key in the Table B, but you could probably find a natural key anyway, such as `{msgid, sendtime}`.

The following query will give you the record in Table B with the highest sendtime.
Let me know if this is what you want.

```
select a.msgid
      ,a.recivtime
      ,b.status
  from table_a
  join table_b on(
       b.msgid = a.msgid
  )
 where b.sendtime = (
         select max(b.sendtime)
           from table_b x
          where x.msgid = a.msgid
       )
   and a.transid = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

For this i'am assuming that you want to solve some kind of "get the newest entry for a specific msgid from tableb"-problem with a 1:n relationship (one table_a.msgid connects to multipble table_b.msgid records):

---

I do this with three views to accomplish this. Every record must have a primary key with is just an numeric value. using the msgid isn't enough. First i select the "newest" record-id for each msgid from table_b using the hightest "id"-Values (which is my primary column and just a growing value). The idea behind this is "the newest entry in table_b (for each msgid) has the highest primary key:

```
create view table_b_max as 
select msgid, max(id) from tableb
group by msgid
```

then i use this "max"-view (which contains only the msgid and the highest corresponding id) to select the full records:

```
create view table_b_max_full
select b.* from table_b b, table_b_max b_max
where b.id = b_max.max_id and 
      b.msgid = b_max.msg_id
```

after that i join table_a and table_b_max_full

```
create view table_a_b   
    select a.*, b.* from table_a a, table_b_max_full b
    where a.msgid = b.msgid (+)
```

And now you can access the "newest" status of a table_a_b using the msgid.

```
select * from table_a_b where msgid = ?
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the ans, I am sorry I don't have enough privilege to create view. Also please note in table B there is no ID column at all, relation is like for a record (message id) in table A , its corresponindg status will get insert in table B, but intention is while running report query should fetch one record from tableB

Comment: ok. this is not related to you problem but if you ever do refactoring in the future then consider to add a simple primary key "id" column to each table (even if you dont use it in your app). because every table should have a "data independent" primary key. this is just some kind of "best practice" advice i've learned from stackoverflow.

Comment: thanks for advice … I will do keep in my mind to suggest this